# DropZone - How to cancel uploading and remove from queue the correct way

Tags: javascript, php, user-interface, frontend, dropzone.js

I need to alert the user if he's uploading and existing (on the server) file; i've done it on `accept` function, like this:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("form#allegati", {
    acceptedFiles: "image/*,.docx,application/pdf",
    url: "allegati.php", // Set the url,
    dictRemoveFileConfirmation: "Sei sicuro?",
    maxFilesize: 10,
    thumbnailWidth: 80,
    thumbnailHeight: null,
    parallelUploads: 20,
    createImageThumbnails: true,
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    autoQueue: true, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
    previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
    clickable: ".fileinput-button", // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
    accept: function (file, done) {
        var idIncarico = GetURLParameter('idIncarico');
        $.ajax({
            // AJAX POST TO CHECK IF FILE EXISTS ON THE SERVER (RETURN TRUE/FALSE)
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'allegati.php?checkExisting=true&id='+idIncarico,
            data: { fileName: file.name },
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                // ASKS THE USER TO OVERWRITE 
                if (data) {
                    var q = confirm("File esistente. Vuoi sovrascrivere?");
                    if (q == false){
                        // IF USER CANCEL UPLOAD:
                        done("no");
                    } else {
                        // IF USER CONFIRM UPLOAD:
                        done();
                    }
                } else {
                    done();
                }
            }
        });
    },
    init: function() {
        this.on("error", function(file){
            // I GET HERE WHEN USER CLICK ON "CANCEL"
            console.log(myDropzone);
        });
    [CUTTED]
```

Every seems to work except when the user cancel the upload: the queued file stays there.

I should not call removeFile(file) because I have an ajax script, also bound to every single file "delete" button, that removes existing file from the server (because of the same filename)...

Is there a way to remove the rejected one without calling `removeFile(file)`?

Screenshot attached
[image: schermata 2015-11-24 alle 00 16 22]

Alex

Comment: If you only remove a file by its name, it occurs to me that an easy solution can be to change the file name to a dummy name like `file.name = 'dummy.zzz'` and then call `removeFile(file)`

Comment: ...interesting; I will try it for sure, thanks

Comment: @wallek87 Great! It worked, thank you.